# Xcode project dependencies graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift/Objective C and Xcode. I am having hard time to understand a project which i have downloaded from GitHub. The project is very big, written in both Objective C and Swift, also includes pods.

What I was trying to generate a dependency graph of the entire code base that includes Classes, Struct etc. So that i can understand the entire hierarchy of classes, structs, functions, protocols, delegates etc. in that project.

I did find some open source tool in the GitHub but those are not able to generate the entire dependency tree/graph. And also i was trying to find, whether there is anyway I could trace the classes, functions, delegates etc that is being called while executing the app in the simulator other than putting a breakpoints.

I would highly appreciate if some can help me to find the right tools, so that it can help me to understand a big code base.

Answer (score 2):

I found some good tools to do the what you ask for, e.g. https://github.com/PrzemyslawCholewaDev/swift-dependency-visualizer
But if the project gets too big, it is not very helpful anymore, since every  class is drawn on the same plane.
Then you should try https://swiftalyzer.com. It generates an interactive map of all of your modules, xcode groups and classes and draws dependencies between those. Very very good, but it's lacking objc support.

Answer (score 1):

By default, xCode has a Symbol Navigator as a part of it. It's not really what you're looking for but at least it's something.

[image]

When I've investigated the topic last time, I’ve found some tools for converting your iOS project to UML diagrams. And I should say it didn’t help a lot to understand the project structure, especially given the fact that UIKit likes inheriting very much. You’ll get a mass of useless information.

So, in my humble opinion, it’s much more useful just figure out the project architecture and how it implements the navigation between controllers.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, I would definitely try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a tool [Build Graph for Xcode](https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/build-graph-for-xcode/id1592897820?l=en&mt=12) to visualise dependencies between modules, would be usefull if your app has separate packages or projects.